# How to assert if a lambda has been called

Tags: java, lambda, mockito, junit5, assertj

I'm currently working with lambda (Consumer or Function) as a parameter of my methods.

And I'm wondering what is the best way to assert if the lambda has been executed.

I've found 2 solution and I wonder which one is the better or if something else exists.

1. Use a list and add Object each time the consumer is called

```java
   List<Object> listCall = new ArrayList<>()
   myObject.myMethod((param)->listCall.add(param))
   asserThat(listCall).hasSize(wantedNumberCall)
```

**Pro**: This is working. You can count the number of call

**Cons**: Feel a little awkward to add this custom lambda just for testing something like that

2. Use Mockito to mock your Consumer/Function

```java
   myObject.myMethod(consumerMock)
   Mockito.verify(consumerMock,Mockito.times(0)).apply(any());
```

**Pro**: Mockito have a lot of option to count call with argument.

**Cons**: Mockito doesn't recommend to mock objects you don't own. And it need to mock sometimes more than just apply(Consumer) or accept (Consumer)

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: Junit 5 with assertj and mockito

Comment: Just so I have this right, `myMethod` takes in a lambda expression, and you want to check if that lambda expression has executed?

Comment: I would just say to check the *effect* of the lambda, in the example you provided, the size of the `listCall`.  You only need to test something like if a lambda executed is if it is part of an API/library.

Comment: Mockito seems a natural choice to verify interactions.

Comment: Yes natural but in fact i'm not the garant of how Consumer/Function work ? 
So if i misunderstood one of the method for example andThen my test will be wrong (even if he pass)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit overkill, but nothing comes to mind except of using the StackWalker to completely separate the assert from the lambda. Just assert your `consumerMock` is where it should be in the stack

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html

Comment: Yes, I think this is a bit overkill.  Tests should be as simple as possible.  But, +1, as I didn't know about `StackWalker` before.